# Git Workflow for Multiple Feature Branches

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Let's say I'm working on a feature that involves changes to multiple components of a system. As an example, let's say I need to update a daemon, server, and client. My current workflow would leave me with branches/commits like this:

```
m1---m2---m3  <- master
           \
            d1---d2  <- daemon
                  \
                   s1---s2  <- server
                         \
                          c1---c2  <- client
```

With these branches, I could create 3 pull requests on GitHub, merging `client -> server`, `server -> daemon`, and `daemon -> master`. This all works fine, until I need to add a commit on a branch other than `client`. For example, let's say I make a commit on `daemon`:

```
m1---m2---m3  <- master
           \
            d1---d2---d3  <- daemon
                  \
                   s1---s2  <- server
                         \
                          c1---c2  <- client
```

Now I'm left in "rebase hell", where I need to rebase `server` onto `daemon`, `client` onto `server`, etc. Is there a way to move `s1` to `d3` and take downstream branches like `client` with it in one command? Thus leaving a final state like this and my pull requests in tact:

```
m1---m2---m3  <- master
           \
            d1---d2---d3  <- daemon
                       \
                       s1---s2  <- server
                             \
                             c1---c2  <- client
```

Comment: I don't really see the benefit of using 3 separate branches when you are in fact working with one feature. Are you sure you really need those?

Comment: @1615903 what alternative would you recommend? I don't want to include all components in the same pull request, because review would be overwhelming

Comment: Note that in the next upcoming Git, `git rebase --interactive` will have the machinery in it for doing this in one Git command. I'm not sure how well it will work in practice initially but this is the thing I'd made my own horrible hack for many years ago (mine didn't have the fancy stuff that the new interactive rebase has).

Answer (score 1):

It may feel like it's "rebase hell", but the reality is you only need a single rebase command, and then you simply need to repoint the middle branch(es) to their new respective commits. So that's 1 rebase command followed by `n-2` branch resets, where `n` is the number of PR's (branches) you will have. In your example with 3 branches it's kind of a two-liner:

```
git rebase d2 client --onto d3
# Now for each middle branch, reset to the corresponding new commit ID:
# Look at the log of client to see the new s2 ID
git branch -f server <new-commit-id-of-s2>
```

If you had *many* branches chained in this way or you needed to do this often, surely you could automate the reset portion if desired (e.g. commit messages and author name/dates will be the same, etc). However, considering that branching in this way is (generally) a theoretical anti-pattern, I hope it wouldn't happen often enough to warrant spending too much time automating something that can be done manually quickly enough.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you should only need to merge `daemon` and `client` with `master` if you're branching in this manner but, it's not really an ideal way to split work unless each upstream change is dependent on the previous component and even then you might want to save integration for the overall feature release/merge rather than doing it at each child component.

In Example 2 all commits but `d3` are already in `client` so you could simplify your workflow(s) to either 1, 2, or 3 steps:

- **Example 1**: merging `client -> master` brings in everything.
- **Example 2**: merging `client -> master` brings in everything but `d3`. Cherry pick (or rebase commit only) `d3` to client or master.
- **Example 2** (alt - simplest): Merging `daemon -> client -> master` would bring in `d3` and `server`.
- **Example 2** (alt 2): Merge upstream branches (`daemon`, `server`) before downstream PR (`client -> master`).

A safer way to do this might be to simply branch master once to create an integration branch and then branch and merge (when resolving) each component so you can test their interoperability without updating your production branch. This would be where you're doing reviews and then merging that to master once release is ready.

This, of course, means 1 more merge rather fewer but wouldn't involve branching feature chaining and would make it easier to catch bugs before release. Sometimes you don't want the fewest merges or the cleanest history, you want guardrails.